# Looking for any way to increment ENUM type without operator overloading

Tags: c++, enums

so this is about an assignment.

I have a header file with predefined ENUM type (`TDay`) which I CANNOT change in any way. `TDay` does not support any operator other than streams.

My problem is I need to find a way to do something like this:

```
Object::Object (uint aSize) {
    Object temp; // contains varible inicialized to zero, this variable can be bool, int, RGB structure 
                 // or TDay enum. I also can't use templates here.
    for (int i = 0; i < aSize; i++) {
        this->array[i] = temp.Value() + 1; // array is of the same type as Value
    }
}
```

This code is just for illustration of what I need to do, don't look for any use of this I just made it up just to better explain my problem.

So anyway this doesn't work because my TDay doesn't support TDay+int operator.

Is there any way around this? Solution doesn't have to be clean, I'll accept any pointer cheats.

EDIT:

So I tried putting in my Object.cpp file this:

```
TDay operator+(TDay aDay, int aValue) {
    return static_cast<TDay>(int(aDay) + aValue);
}
```

And it doesn't work. Compiler error says:

```
Argument of type int is imcompatible with parameter of type TDay
```

However if I put this code to TDay.h it works fine. Is something wrong with my linker?

Comment: i can do whatever I want with my object, so yes copy and you can assume all members are public

Comment: Why not a free-standing `TDay operator+(TDay day, int i) { return (TDay)((int)day + i); }`? You could even define this locally in your related C++ source so that no other code will be "infected" by this.

Comment: When I was trying to figure out the solution I tried `TDay operator+(TDay day, int i) { return (static_cast<TDay>(int(day) + i)); }` and it didn't work. So I assumed I can't do that. Does this work?

Comment: _and it didn't work_: Expose this code, and copy/paste the compiler complaints. I would wonder if this wouldn't work: [sample on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71f491029ad75857).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including the code you have tried and didn't work

Comment: enumerated types are not meant to be iterated over via ++. That's an implementation detail leaking. You are not always guaranteed they start at 0 and increment by 1. You're also not always guaranteed the backing type will be `int`. The way to iterate over enums is to put all the enumerated values into a list and then iterate over that.

Comment: @Scheff I updated my question with further information.

Comment: If `TDay` is an `enum` (or even an `enum class`) it should work (like shown im my [mcve on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71f491029ad75857)). Please, expose the definition of `TDay`. (Sorry, again: [mcve] required.)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a function taking current ENUM value named for example increase

```
void increase(your_enum& e){
    if(e == e::MAX_VAL)
        e = e::MIN_VAL; //if you have it, otherwise do same as below
    else{
        int val = int(e); //cast it to int
        val++;
        e = static_cast<your_enum>(val); //cast it back
    }
}
```

Creating a function taking another parameter to increase/decrease by more than one should be easy from this point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This looks better than some shady pointer cheats but could get quite long with more types. Will use it if I don't find anything better. Thank you!